# How to open application by URL in SMS in Swift

Tags: swift, swift2

I want to open my application from a URL in SMS.

I can receive a SMS, and there is a URL SMS. I have a question for that:

When I click the URL in SMS, How can I open my application and analyse the URL in my application ?

I have searched in internet, but I can not find a right answer...Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

Comment: I found [link](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-deep-linking-in-swift/), but it doesn't work.. I use `https:/abc.def.io/`, How I set `URL Schemes` ? and `URL identifier` ?

Comment: I think you're looking for a deep link rather than a URL Scheme

Answer (score -1):

We can use function `func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?)`